# Writing my own Google Mobile Ads (Admob) mediation adapter

Tags: android, admob, adsense

Instead of using house ads I would like to create my own SDK for displaying adverts within my apps. I would like to run this alongside normal Google Mobile Ads and control how often my own SDK displays ads via the mediation settings in the Admob dashboard.

Existing mobile networks offer [mediation adapters](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/mediation-networks) for this purpose. I would like to write my own adapter but cannot find any documentation that explains how this is done.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admob provides CustomEventBanner and CustomEventInterstitial classes with which you can do exactly that.

See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/custom-events

Comment: @ZaidPathan I have updated the URL to the new location.